# Timeout heavy server

Tags: performance, timer, delegates

I need a server to perform lots of timing operations and trigger code accordingly.
So I'll break my wonderings into simple questions:

1. How are timeout and timeout callback usually work in terms of OS resources and threads?
   (say the nodejs `setTimeout(callback, delay)`)
2. Should I refrain from that and maybe have a timer worker to check every second for timeouts?
   e.i. if i need 10 timeouts, keep a collection of all timeout timestamps and check every second if any of them is due.
3. What would be a good framework / platform to implement this kind of behaviour?

Please comment if you think I'm being unclear,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"Depends"

Most timer implementations are extremely lightweight (i.e. having zillions of timers going at once). A timer core is little more than a priority queue of "things soon to expire", and then expiring them every second.

Things are different when lots of them fire all at once, that is NOT lightweight (as all the real work starts).